# lightning Process fires validation rules on record creation

Tags: process-builder, validation-rule

I have validation rule on Opportunity like this:

```
NOT( ISNEW() ) && ISBLANK( MY_Field )
-----
Error Message: Please select "MY_Field" to save this record
```

It worked fine. Then I created a Process which updates a field on opportunity every time a record is created or updated. Now, when I try to create new opportunity record, I am not able to save it. Below error is generated:

`An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate).
UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS : (FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION) Please select "MY_Field" to save this record.`

Also an email is sent which describe the error.

As per the code of validation rule, on record creation this error should not occur.

Any Idea why process cause to fire this validation rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Process builder.

I have confirmed that a WFR that Updates the Name of a record when created in the presence of a validation rule with criteria `NOT(ISNEW())` works correctly.

So it would seems you will have to go the WFR route for now.

Comment: I am populating a lookup field  in this Process that is why I cannot use a WFR.

Comment: @abdn - the a properly written trigger it is

Comment: Logged a case with salesforce, lets see what they say. Have to write a trigger now :(

Comment: @abdn - Please mark as correct answer so others having the same issue can find answers to their question and so it does not keep surfacing as unanswered